# Sized table with at most one line of content per cell with Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm trying to display a table (with given column width using Bootstrap's `col-md-X`) with at most one line of (text) content per cell. Refer to the last example in my jsfiddle for an example of what I'd want.

I use this oneliner css class to limit the amount of text displayed :

```
.oneliner {
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

I have two issues:

- When the text in a cell is too long, it breaks the size I've set. It can be fixed by using a custom size class instead of bootstrap, but I would prefer to avoid using this method since sizes of columns vary from `col-md-1` to `col-md-12` in production tables, plus it doesn't solve next issue :
- When applying my `.oneliner class`, it puts all the text in a single line, streching the parent (even with my custom sizing class), event if I apply in on a `<span>` or `<p>` inside my `<td>`.

JSFiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/85TjP/2/ (updated)

I would really like to avoid using js for this.

Answer (score 2):

See the below for an example of how this can be accomplished:

## **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32RGz/10/)**

Crucially applying the following properties to an element will ensure only one line of text is displayed and it doesnt resize:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow:hidden;
```

You can use the below for ellipses to appear if any text overflows, for visual purposes only:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

HTML

```
<div class='table'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell'>Something quite long</div>
        <div class='cell'>here is some moreSomething quite long that should exceed the table cell.Something quite long that should exceed the table cell.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would have prefered a more semantic way of doing it (I am, after all, displaying a table). I would also prefer to stick with bootstrap 3 (without having to copy-pase css from boostrap to custom made classes). Not to mention my real-case table(s) isn't(aren't) limited to two columns of the same width.

Comment: The above is an example, with explanatory code only. Can you give an actual production example/html? Have you tried simply applying  `white-space: nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;` to the table cell you want the behaviour on?

Comment: Yes I tried adding this css to my table, without success, I'll update question and JSfiddle for a more precise explanation

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, found the solution.

Applying `style="table-layout: fixed;"` to the table fixes both problems, the final html+css would look like :

CSS

```
.oneliner {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="table" style="table-layout: fixed;">
    <tr>
        <th class="col-md-6">Some title</th>
        <th class="col-md-6">Other title</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Short row</td>
        <td class="oneliner">Much, much longer row, this is so long it's going to overflow</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Of course `table-layout : fixed;` should be applied via CSS